# What is the best way to use the .SaveChanges() method in ADO.Net Data Services?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services, savechanges

Does anyone have some good information on the usage of the .SaveChanges() method?

I am experiencing a variety of issues when attempting to use the .SaveChanges() method on my data context object.  I am taking data from an existing data source, creating the appropriate EntityFramework/DataService objects, populating those created objects with data, adding those objects to the context and then saving that data by calling .SaveChanges.

The scenarios I've come up with (and the problems associated with them) are as such ... In each scenario I have a foreach loop that is taking data from rows in a DataTable and generating the objects, attaching them to the context as they go. (note: three objects a "member" and two "addresses" that are attached via a SetLink call) - basically this is a conversion tool to take data from one data store and massage it into a data store that is exposed by Data Services.

- Call .SaveChanges() without any parameters once at the end of the foreach loop (i.e. outside the loop)

  - OutOfMemory error about 1/3 of the way (30,000 out of 90,000 saves) - not sure how that is happening though as each save item is a seperate SQL call to the database, what is there to run out of memory on?
- Call .SaveChanges() without any parameters once per loop

  - This works, but takes absolutly forever (8 hours for 90,000 saves)
- Call .SaveChanges(SaveChangesOption.Batch) once at the end of the foreach loop

  - Same OutOfMemory error, but without any saves to the database
- Call .SaveChanges(SaveChangesOption.Batch) once per loop

  - 404 not found error
- Call .SaveChanges(SaveChangesOption.Batch) once per 10 loops

  - 400 Bad Request error (occassionally)
  - OutOfMemory after a number of itterations
- A number of random attempts to create the context once per loop, or have it as a variable at the start of the loop or have it as a private member variable that is available.

  - Differing results, unable to quantify, none really that good

What is the prefered method of calling .SaveChanges() from a client object when doing a large data load like this?  Is there something I'm not getting about how .SaveChanges() works?  Can anyone provide more details on how once should be utilizing this function and what (if any) are the limitations to saving data via Data Services?  Are there any best practices around the .SaveChanges() method call?  Is there any particularly good documentation on the .SaveChanges() method call?

Comment: what "changes" are you implementing? Why 90,000 saves? Maybe you should try SQL replication, if you're just passing data? just a thought.

Comment: just to clarify, when you say "once per loop" you mean one call per loop *iteration* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no big experience in using EntityFramework (just some random experiment), have you tried calling .SaveChanges() every n iterations?

I mean something like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    // do something with your data
    if ((i++ % 10) == 0)
        context.SaveChanges();
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

I know it's ugly, but it's the first possible solution i came up with.

Comment: this does appear to be one of the better solutions available (in particular balancing memory usage and speed) - it does seem to perform better the larger you make the n itterations number (until you hit memory limit).  i still don't have a definitive method that works in all situations yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am using EntityFramework on a small project also so I am very interested in the question also. 
Two quick questions:
   Have you tried to turn of the caching og the data objects in the datacontext? 
   Have you tried to close the datacontext and created a new one during the loop to free up memory?

Regards

Kenneth

Comment: creating a new context during the loop does free up memory which does help, but then makes the saves longer (there seems to be some improvements by processing larger groups of items).  how does one turn of the caching of the data objects?